# Encriptar parâmentro GET do JS/PHP

Tags: php, javascript, angularjs, criptografia

Qual a melhor maneira de trafegar dados entre JS e PHP vie método GET?
Imagine uma requisição $http feita no angularjs passando paramentos ex: **minhaurl?id=2&nome="joao"**

O ideal seria encriptar os parametros. Mas o BASE64 apresenta falha em relação ao UTF8.

Sendo assim,como enviar dados de forma criptografada via GET e descriptografar em PHP e enviar as respostas criptografadas em PHP e desencriptar no js?

Comment: É obrigatório utilizar o método get?

Comment: Se está falando de segurança base64 não é para encriptar e nem nenhum método que eu conheça vai lhe servir assim, creio que o caminho seja usar HTTPS.

Comment: Na verdade não. Poderia usar o POST. Mas minha dúvida é se seria possível tornar o GET seguro. Mesmo que eu use o POST, ainda assim seria possível qualquer pessoal capturar os headers e inspecionar as variáveis. o que torna insegura minha aplicacao. Assim independente de GET ou POST. Como criptografar e garantir as decodificacoes no JS/PHP

Comment: Para utilizar o get de forma segura necessitaria utilizar um certificado de SSL e utilizar o HTTPS. E a forma mais segura ainda é pelo método post.

Comment: O JWT ainda tem muitas falhas ...

Comment: Qualquer criptografia seria insegura no *client side*, já que pode-se saber qual algorítimo foi usado para criptografar. Você precisa que os dados sejam criptografados no PHP antes de renderizar o HTML - o ID `1` passa a ser `a3d296261dbda886e8685e4bad338bf4`

Comment: Base64 não é criptografia e base64 não tem nenhum problema com UTF-8. E não adianta "criptografar" nada no lado do JS, pois pode ser desfeito com tranquilidade. Mesmo que você mande uma chave diferente para o JS a cada requisição, quem intercepta a comunicação vai ter acesso a ela. HTTPS é o que dá para fazer (e mesmo assim, contra terceiros, pois do lado do cliente, tudo é acessível).

Comment: Apresenta algumas falhas sim: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30106476/using-javascripts-atob-to-decode-base64-doesnt-properly-decode-utf-8-strings

Comment: Tenta criptografar o conteúdo dos dados utilizando a biblioteca Crypto-js:
https://github.com/brix/crypto-js